# In Python, how to flatten nested lists? how to make Python iterate (once) over single elements?

Tags: python, iterator

How do I get a single instance (like an int, or a str) to be iterable. A.k.a, how do I flatten the list that may contain nested lists.
This is important.  Consider that a list (or a function return) can contains an iterable, like a list or a generator, but it can also contain single values.  And I have to process them.
In the below example, I have a list that contains singular elements as well as lists of elements.  And I just want to flatten them to a simple list.
How do I do that?

```
org_l = [[1,2,3,4],[5],6,7,[8,9,0]]
new_l = [e1 for e in l for e1 in e]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krisv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 101, in <module>
    l = [e1 for e in l for e1 in e]
  File "C:\Users\krisv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 101, in <listcomp>
    l = [e1 for e in l for e1 in e]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

what's needed is new_l that is equal to:
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question:

```
def unroll(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, typing.Iterable) and not isinstance(thing, str):
        for e in thing:
            yield from unroll(e)
    else:
        yield thing

l = [[1,2,[3,'c'],4],[5],6,7,7.5,[8,9,9.5,0]]
flat_list = [e for e in unroll(l)]
print(flat_list)
>>>
[1, 2, 3, 'c', 4, 5, 6, 7, 7.5, 8, 9, 9.5, 0]
```